# check how many counts have values that are <>0 in powerquery M

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a table in power query that contains columns like "account, date, P1, P2, P3.....P12".
P1 to P12 have numerical values that can be 0, negative or positive.
I need to check in each row how many columns between P1 and P12 have values <> 0 so that I can ignore those, any way to do that?
I'm not expert at all with M

Thanks

I think i need to use a list.count but I'm not sure how (and maybe i'm completely wrong). How tried to use the count function but it doesn't let me add conditions

Answer (score 0):

Powerquery, one method, explicitly specifying which columns NOT to check

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
remove={"A"},
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,remove),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Count", each List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(_), each if _<>0 then 1 else 0))),
final =Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source)&{#"Added Custom"[Count]},Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"Count"})
in  final
```

[image]

it removes the extra columns, uses Record.FieldValues() to get all the items on that row, checks for zeroes, sums that, then recombines that column with original data

you could also specify the specific columns to check (rather then columns to exclude in other method)

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
keep={"P1","P2","P3","P4","P5","P6","P7","P8","P9","P10","P11","P12"},
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Source,keep)
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Count", each List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(_), each if _<>0 then 1 else 0))),
final =Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source)&{#"Added Custom"[Count]},Table.ColumnNames(Source)&{"Count"})
in  final
```